# Mod Rewrite: Handling two Get Variables

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I edit this url rewrite to include a further get variable being appended to the URL? I have tried a few attemps but I always get a 500 internal server error!

I have added comments to show what I am trying to achieve.

```
# /view.php?user=h5k6&page=1 externally to /h5k6/1
# Some times the page get variable will not exist so it should just show /h5k6
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /view\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*user=([^&]+)&?.*$
RewriteRule ^view\.php$ /%2? [L,R=301]

# /h5k6/1 internally to /view.php?t=h5k6&page=1
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)$ view.php?t=$1 [L]
```

Thanks all for any help

Comment: @Gumbo - there isn't an error with the above, but when I edit the htaccess file to include another get variable, I get an error (500 internal server error) - I am hoping to find out how to edit the above **correctly** to include two GET variables and rewrite the URL as in my comments, `/h5k66/1`. First segment being the user GET variable and the second be the page GET variable.

Comment: @Abs: Then how do you try to include another GET argument?

Comment: I had a few guesses, the last one I have just tried is: `^([^&]*&)*user=([^&]+)&?.*$([^&]*&)*page=([^&]+)&?.*$` - which is just a copy of the previous get variable "user". This hasn't worked.

Comment: @Abs: What now: It just didn’t work or it caused an internal error?

Comment: With the above, I get a 500 internal server error. If I remove it, its fine. Is my syntax correct for two get variables?

Comment: @Abs: It seems to be correct syntactically. But it doesn’t make that much sense semantically. Because the `$` marks the end of the string and there cannot be anything after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with URI query arguments is that they may appear in any order. With two arguments you just have two permutations (*A before B* and *B before A*). But the more arguments you want to extract the more permutations you have ([*n*!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)).

That means you should put the arguments in the right order so that you can them at a time:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /view\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)(page=[^&]+)&?([^&].*)?$
RewriteCond %3&%1%4 ^(([^&]*&)*)(user=[^&]+)&?([^&].*)?$
RewriteCond %3&%1%4 ^user=([^&]+)&page=([^&]+)&?([^&].*)?$
RewriteRule ^view\.php$ /%1/%2?%3 [L,R=301]
```

The first condition checks the request line like in your rule. The second condition picks the *page* argument and puts it at the start of the query string. The third condition does the same with the *user* argument so that the order always is: first *user*, second *page*. Then we use the fourth condition to take both argument values at a time to use them in the `RewriteRule` replacement. The rest of the query is appended to the replacement URI (see `%3`) but you can leave that off if you want.

As you see, the more arguments you want to extract, the more complex it gets. And it is easier to do that with a language that is more powerful than mod_rewrite like PHP.

Comment: You are right, this is going to get complicated. I have started re-writing my project using codeigniter and I think I can make use of routing.