# How to use mode_rewrite function

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to know, how I can use php's function mode_rewrite correctly.
I'm currently developing with xampp. I've activated `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in the httpd.conf file.
Also I edited following lines:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

In my .htaccess file, I've following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?m=$1 [L]
```

So it should change `?m=start` to `?start.html`.
When I now open `localhost/page/start.html`, it only shows me "It works". But why doesn't it show me the content from `localhost/page/?m=start` ?

A further question would be, how do I change the rewrite rule, that I could access `localhost/page/?m=start&set=update` through `localhost/page/start/update.html`?

Thank you for an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the absolute path `/` in your substitution. So when using this rule in the .htaccess file in `/page/` a request of `/page/start.html` will actually be rewritten to `/?m=start` and not `/page/?m=start`.

Try a relative path instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ ./?m=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Wow, very fast response :) Thanks, it's working now.
Could you also tell me, how I can solve my second problem?
I've for example this localhost/page/?m=kontakt. When I've sent the form on this page, the url looks like localhost/page/?m=kontakt&set=update. How must the rewrite rule look like?

Comment: @Damian Frizzi: Oh, didn’t see that. Well, in that case you need to use a `RewriteCond` and look at the value of `%{QUERY_STRING}`. But to avoid mutual recursion, you also need to look at `%{THE_REQUEST}` or check for a response status code. That’s a little more complicated. So in case you are using not just static files but a programming language, you should better use that programming language to do that redirect.

Comment: Puh, that's a little bit hard to understand for me. I've never worked with this before. Where do I get the value of %{QUERY_STRING} and %{THE_REQUEST}? I'm using php, how can I use this language to do a redirect?

Comment: @Damian Frizzi: Take a look at these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217981/htaccess-rewrite-issue/1219119#1219119, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054738/rewriterule-loop-redirection/4054803#4054803, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938699/rewrite-url-to-index-php-but-avoid-index-php-in-the-url/2938734#2938734 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852386/mod-rewrite-handling-two-get-variables/2865531#2865531